# Does everyone see the same Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-go

I was wondering if everyone sees the same Pokémon on the map. If I catch all the Pokémon around me will others be unable to get any?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

From [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4ou4uh/does_everyone_see_the_same_pokemon_on_their_map/) I found out:

- Same Pokémon spawns for every player in the same place.
- Every player can catch it.
- Once it is caught by one of the players, other players who faced it can still catch it.
- Combat Power depends on the respective player's level.

Intensive playing of the game proved those facts. Incense might bring different results as it has only impact for the user.

Comment: Ok thats interesting. The thing is at our workplace there seem to be no pokemon at all since everyone plays it there. Not sure if this is just coincidence though.

Comment: @Gigala So you assumed a stealthy trainer who catched 'em all? :P

Comment: Not only one, we are like 100 people there and im sure most of them got the game so i thought they constantly grab all the pokemon :) edit: i have a theory that if you see them at the same time both can catch it but if someone catches it and you log on later its gone. No idea if thats the way it works though

Comment: So other people around you also benefit from your incense or is that an exception?

Comment: Today at a park, there was a couple playing and I heard out-loud one of them ask the other if they had caught it. However, there was no Pokemon on my screen at all. Would it be possible that the Android and Apple in-game worlds are actually different instances?

Comment: So I'm wondering if they key here is "... other players who faced it can still catch it." Is it if you initiate against a pokemon before being captured, you can all get it?

Comment: There is an exception to this rule: Pokemon that appear as a result of using Incense will *only appear for you*. Nobody else will see them. Pokemon that appear at Lure Modules however are visible to everyone.

Comment: Ok now that I have some experience playing with a friend and going for a few walks I can say this: When we encountered a pokemon we can **both** catch it. It then stays on the map for a while. It only happened rarely that one could catch it and the other one was too slow (cause his app was closed) I assume this is because the Pokemon get cleared every X Minutes. If your app is open at the same time you should be safe though.

Comment: Can you edit this to make it clearer that it doesn't matter if you faced it or not before someone else catches it? Everyone can catch it until it despawns, end of story,

Answer (score 72):

I went for a walk with my gf.
We found the exact same Pokemon on the same spot and we could both catch them

Comment: yeah i observed the same thing when walking around with a friend yesterday. I guess its like this: If you see the same pokemon you can both catch it but if someone else catches the pokemon and you go there much later than him you dont get to catch it.

Answer (score 13):

h0ch5tr4355 gave a great, detailed answer, which I wanted to expand upon with interesting facts. In addition to being in the same place for every player, certain attributes like size and weight are the same before capturing. While HP is dependent on CP, which is dependent on player level, the following are the same for all players:

- Size (weight and height)
- Moves

I did an experiment ([5 Players, Same Pokemon](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vj7rq1kn520h4d0/AABKHX8RTLlU-yFaR3i0iKrha?dl=0)) using 5 accounts, catching the same Pidgey in the same location on all of them. Three of the accounts were level 8, while the other two were level 7. Interestingly, the lvl 8 accounts all got a 92CP Pidgey with 27HP. The lvl 7 accounts got a 109CP Pidgey with 30HP. Usually, higher player levels result in higher CP wild Pokemon, but it was kind of randomized in this experiment. I know 5 players is a sample size, but assuming this is true for all cases, here's what we can deduce from the experiment:

- A Pokemon's size and moveset are predetermined when it spawns (prior to capture)
- Upon capture, players of the same level will be given the same randomized CP (e.g. 92)

I also remember one time when a kid and I of the same level (6) caught an Arcanine, it was both 301CP exactly, but 838CP for a level 16 guy. So I am pretty confident that my experiment wasn't flawed. But feel free to comment if you have had the same experience or different.

EDIT: From [this](https://redd.it/4uf85m) reddit post, it has been confirmed that IV ranges are also predetermined. By "ranges", I mean that the distribution of IVs for Attack, Defense, and Stamina have multiple possible combinations, but they roughly equal the same number total when added.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was wondering if spawned Pokemon have the same IVs for anyone who catches them and this answers that. You didn't directly mention the basis for your conclusion on move sets; I assume you did compare these and they were the same for all players? Or just all players on the same level?

Comment: @TimMalone My 3 accounts were level 8 and the other 2 were level 7, all with the same moveset (Quick Attack / Aerial Ace). So regardless of level, the moveset will still be the same.

Comment: IVs are fixed as well, Pokemon level is random, but always the same for a specific trainer level (and can generally be higher for lower level trainers as long as it's no higher than trainer level +2). Since CP are calculated based on base stats, IVs and pokemon level, they are also identical for trainers of the same level. So basically, everything about the pokemon is fixed when it spawns, except for the level, which is determined randomly for each trainer level.

Comment: The EDIT portion is now outdated.

Answer (score 7):

The Pokemon only stay in place for short amount of time, regardless of if they've been caught. At work, somebody will announce that they caught something & the rest of us will log in and catch it. It doesn't disappear before we log in. Looks like you just work somewhere where there aren't a lot spawning

Answer (score 2):

the last answer is accurate. my husband will walk down the street then come back home stating which pokemom he caught. i will then walk/drive to get to the same location and log on, and l the same pokemon is always there if i get there within atleast 5mins...if i go like 10mins after then it wont be there, but i know if get there within 5 mins it will be there. There have been a few occasions where we will be walking tpgether and his screen with show a pokemom and mine will not..this is bc different phones have quicker and slower server connections but most of the time when one is on his screen, i will wait 10seconds, and then the same one will show up on mine. There have been a few times where a pokemom will show up on his and not on mine at all...this goes back to the server on each phone... my phone must have had a server "jump" or "spaz" if you will so it will not locate that pokemon. Hope this helps!

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes. Answer is correct and helpful (if anecdotal). +1.

Answer (score 2):

Pokemon spawned into the world normally or by lure modules will be visible and catchable by everyone in that area (good thing too, or there would be fights over rare ones!)

However, pokemon attracted by incense (the item that attracts pokemon to your location) will only be visible and catchable by the person who used the incense.

If you are out with a group and they find a pokemon you don't, take a few steps in every direction, or simply wait a few moments. It's likely just a matter of you loading it into your game a little more slowly.

Answer (score 1):

in short, if everyone is at the same spot where a pokemon is they will all see it unless 1) there phone has had a server "jump"/"spaz" where it did not pick up that pokemon or 2) if the pokemon at that spot dissappears before you can log on.

Pokemon usually stay in one spot for atleast 15minutes. i have not tested past this time.

*if you click on the list of pokemon in the bottom right corner, this will pull up the pokemon near you. if you are with someone else, or a few people for that matter, and eveyone pulls up that list it is most likely that everyones will look a bit different. this is because everyones phones are constantly updating and connecting to the pokemon go sever at different times so one phone might update and connect to the server slightly quicker and one might be super slow so i wouldnt worry to much about your list matching someone elses. if you are both, or all, going after the same pokemon and are walking/driving closer and closer to it everyone will eventually see that pokemon on their screen and all have a chance to catch it. i usually let my husband find the pokemon and then when he does i open my app and log on to get the same pokemon so i dont have to waste my battery :D