# Does an incense stack with a lure module?

Tags: pokemon-go

There is a Pokestop near me with a lure module periodically available from another player. If I were to go there, and then activate an incense would that improve the amount of Pokemon that I see?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Incense and Lure Modules will stack to increase the effect rate of that area.

However, the Incense will only benefit you and not other players.

Comment: Another answer contradicts this. Do you have research/evidence to support this claim?

Comment: Beta and actual gameplay.

Comment: @AnthonyStringer I guess http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272681/does-everyone-see-the-same-pokémon is the answer that contradicts it? I assume the answerer didn't take into account using an incense. I commented on the answer to ask for clarification

Comment: Do you happen to know if lure modules stack with other lure modules? There is a place near my work where two poke stops overlap so I was wondering if you can double the effect by placing a lure module on each.

Comment: @Andrew Multiple lures do stack, but they can't be on the same PokeStop.

Comment: What you're offering is anecdotal.  If you had something to go with it, like number of spawns for the 30 minutes with just a Lure, ditto with just Incense, ditto with both Incense and a Lure, that's what I think we're all looking for, and what I think @AnthonyStringer meant.

Comment: @undrline Game data dumps

Answer (score 0):

I asked my friend this, and he says he's confirmed that lures and incense stack with actual gameplay -- he continues to do it, and he's gotten a lot of good Pokémon.