# No Pokemon Nearby

Tags: pokemon-go

Can't seem to get nearby Pokemon besides using incense. I don't live in a rural place because there are multiple gyms and pokestops within my area but no nearby Pokemon. This has been going on since the release. Is there a way to tell the system/Niantic to spawn Pokemon in my location? Also can I update pokestops? I know there are multiple people with this problem so lets try to make this question big so Niantic will fix (after they fix the servers and release the game to the world)

Comment: Try to reinstall the app and see if that does anything for you

Comment: Please ask one question per post

Answer (score -1):

My running theory is that a pokemon spawns, *someone* sees it and catches it right away.  While they're still battling, every phone that loads the area will see it, but once it's caught, then anyone else who checks won't see it anymore. If there's a lot of players in a small area, the odds increase that someone sees it and catches it quickly, and the odds go way down that any will be left standing around when you check.
I see tons of pokemon all weekend at my apartment, and have never yet seen one at work for instance. (TONS of players at my work)

Comment: This answer is directly contradicting the answers to [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272681/does-everyone-see-the-same-pok%c3%a9mon/272685) which say that there is a time window in which a pokemon is available and any number of people can catch it.

Comment: -1 as this is flat out wrong in my experience. I play with multiple friends and we're always able to catch the same pokemon, sometimes minutes apart.

Comment: @Philipp: My answer doesn't contradict that at all.  I'll reword to make it clearer.

Comment: @MooingDuck While I'm at work I play this, and the guy I sit next to and I always try to catch more then one another, we ALWAYS catch the same Pokemon, you're completely wrong.

Comment: @13aal: It's incredibly common for multiple people to catch the same pokemon, especially when playing togeather.  The question is if one catches a pokemon (completely caught, not still battling), then the other opens the game after that, does the second person still see it?  _That_ would disprove my theory.