# If I ignore Pokemon I don't want... could I miss out on other spawns?

Tags: pokemon-go

If I ignore Pokemon that have spawned (for example, if don't want another Pidgey or Doduo), will it prevent some spawning of other Pokemon?

I have seen up to three Pokemon spawn at once during a lure, but I'm wondering - if I ignore all of them, will I potentially 'miss out' on the spawning of other nearby Pokemon? Should I just be trying to catch everything I see, even if I don't want it, so that I see every possible spawn?

(I'm particularly asking regarding during lures, but I imagine the behaviour of the game in this aspect could be the same whether or not there is a lure in place).

Comment: You don't want to be ignoring Pokemon for other reasons.  For example, the best way to level your character is to evolve a lot of pidgeys at once with a lucky egg active.

Comment: I dont totally agree, @SamIam . Yes, it's great for your XP, but when you're low on pokeballs you might want to skip the pidgeys if it doesn't affect other spawns.

Comment: It's that disagreement that lets me go to a Stop that's a fair distance away but I saw as having a Lure active an hour ago, and finding a veritable horde of Pidgey. Since the Stop is right there I get enough Balls to capture them easily, and now I'm lined up to skip two full levels when I do my evolution spree!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you will **not** miss any pokemon. Indeed, pokemon spawns and un-spawns whether you catch them or not.
sources : > [Does everyone see the same Pokémon?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272681/does-everyone-see-the-same-pok%C3%A9mon)

That being said, it's not recommended to avoid catching a pokemon as it rewards you dust, experience and candy.