# Is unown the same letter for every player in a specific spawn?

Tags: pokemon-go

[This article](http://heavy.com/games/2017/02/has-unown-been-found-in-pokemon-go-photos-where-cp-stats-when-screenshots-pics/) says that Unown can be found in Pokemon GO since Gen II update. It also shows that there are several letters.

I'm wondering if the letter of the Unown is specific to the spawn or if different players can have different letters from the same spawned Unown.

Comment: Related [Does everyone see the same Pokemon?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272681/does-everyone-see-the-same-pok%C3%A9mon?) - While mechanics for Unown is still a mystery, I am assuming the spawn mechanics remain the same

Comment: I doubt anyone knows for sure at this point, based on your link, but I think we can make an educated guess based on whether things like IVs, gender, moves, size, and weight are always the same. Would you accept an answer based on that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I am 100 % sure that any pokemon multiple people capture, they will share the same IV, same form (referring to  Dittoes), and same gender. I have caught an unown, along with my grandparents, and we each got an 'I'. Unfortunately, they have not let me provide pictures, but I will include proof ASAP.

Comment: Shiny-ness? Are you are you're referring to the right Pokemon game?

Comment: Yeah, not officially in yet,  but probably for future reference

Comment: Well now that they have added in shiny magicarps it turns out you are wrong. The same magicarp can be shiny for one person and non-shiny for someone else, so that should be removed from your answer